# Is it possible pass a string from the _ViewStart file to my Layoutfile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a Layout File that is used by both my main site and the Admin area. In the Layout I make a call to the MVCSiteMapProvider to generate my layouts. What I would like to do is setup a string in the _ViewStart file that I can pass into the Layout to designate which sitemap to use. Is it possible to pass variables from the _ViewStart down the Layout file and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head you could use [PageData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.pagedata%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

> Provides array-like access to page data that is shared between pages, layout pages, and partial pages.

## _ViewStart

**C#**

```
@{
    PageData["MyString"] = "Test!";
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
@Code
    PageData("MyString") = "Test!"
End Code
```

## _Layout

**C#**

```
@PageData["MyString"]
```

**VB.NET**

```
@PageData("MyString")
```

Comment: Using PageData the what you wrote it give the error "PageData is a property but is used like a method. So I had to write it PAgeData.Add("MyString", "Text"). I still have to test on the Layout page when I get off work tonight.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ViewBag` for it.

In viewstart:

```
@{
   ViewBag.YourString = "any string";
}
```

In Layout:

```
@{
   var str = (string)ViewBag.YourString;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that a `_ViewStart` has direct access to the ViewData. It's a [WebPageBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase(v=vs.111).aspx).

Comment: ViewBag is not being picked up by VS as valid in the _ViewStart file so I don't think this option will work.